# AnguarJS: Problems in my controller

Tags: angularjs, controller

I have a problem in my controller. It is a strange problem and I ask for your intuition more than your knowledge:

My controller:

```
function modificaProdottoCtrl($scope, prodottiService, ingredientiS) {

var vm = this;
vm.modificaProdottoAnnulla = modificaProdottoAnnulla;
vm.modificaProdottoStart = modificaProdottoStart;
vm.modificaProdottoConferma = modificaProdottoConferma;
vm.datiProdotti = prodottiService.datiService;
vm.prodottiTemp = prodottiService.datiService.prodotti;
vm.ingredienti = [];
vm.test = "ciao";

prodottiService.datiService.visualizzaDettaglio = false;



function modificaProdottoStart( prodotto ) {
    prodotto.modifica = !prodotto.modifica;
    vm.datiProdotti.prodotti = [];
    vm.datiProdotti.prodotti.push (prodotto);

    vm.ricetta = prodottiService.ricettaProdotto (prodotto).then (function (response) {
        console.log ("RICETTA CARICATA");
        vm.datiProdotti.visualizzaDettaglio = !vm.datiProdotti.visualizzaDettaglio;
    });

    //Ricavo l'elenco degli ingredienti
    ingredientiS.query().then( function(response) {

        alert (vm.ingredienti);
        vm.ingredienti = response.data;
        alert (vm.ingredienti);

        console.log ("Ingredienti ricevuti");
        return response
    })

    ...
    ...
```

My html:

```
    ... 
<ul ng-controller = "modificaProdottoCtrl as mc">
    <li class="testoNero"> <I>INGREDIENTI</I></li>
    <li ng-repeat="i in mc.ingredienti"> {{i}}</li>
    <li> </li>
    <li> </li>
    <li> <input type="text" ng-model='mc.test'/>  {{mc.test}} </li>
</ul>
...
```

clearly these are just pieces of code. I was too complex to write all the functional part.
My problem is: When I try to update the varibile "vm.ingredienti" within the function "modificaProdottoStart", it is not updated in the view even if the alert function, I make sure that the varibile "vm.ingredienti" has changed.
I have simulated in this little scenario, with Plunker and everything works fine while in my app I ever updating a list in circumstances such as these.
While if the list is on a "service", then I can see updates regularly also on view.

sorry for my bad English

Comment: have you tried `$scope.$apply();` after `vm.ingredienti = response.data;`?

Comment: Thanks for your response. no, because I'm trying to completely eliminate the $scoper variable

Comment: how is vm linked to $scope ?. did you try : $scope.vm = vm; (afer vm variable declaration), then in your code : $scope.vm.ingredienti = response.data;

Comment: vm is not linked to $scope. I use the keyword "as" in the ng-controller to use not the $scope variable

Comment: I am not really sure but the problem might be that you are creating a new instance of the very variable your are trying to update. This causes that the scope counterpart does not get updated.

Comment: It's possibile even if I created the some scenario in Plunker and it works. I want a reference to one object and to work on that...